# Operations inside variables

Tags: python

I want to make a python script that finds the maximum possible output using 2 operations. The problem it says that there is a syntax error at the 2nd to the last line, in the `b` in there. How can I fix it?

```
x = 0
a = int(input("1st number:")) 
c = int(input("2nd number:" )) 
e = int(input("3rd number:" ))
for i in range(4):
    if i == 0:
        b = "+" 
    elif i == 1: 
        b = "-"
    elif i == 2:    
        b = "/"
    else:
        b = "*" 
    for j in range(4):
        if j == 0:
            d = "+" 
        elif j == 1: 
            d = "-" 
        elif j == 2:    
            d = "/" 
        else:
            d = "*" 
        k = a b c d e
        print(k)
```

Comment: Why do you think `k = a b c d e` would work?

Comment: can you use lamda ? or just want edit your own code

Comment: You should look into the `operator` module and assign actual functions to `b` and `d` not just strings, then you could do `d(b(a, c), e)`.

Comment: @AChampion that might not preserve proper operator precedence, though. I'm not sure how trivial that would be to do without `eval`, however.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen very true, but `eval()` is generally considered dangerous. You could always just assign `b` to the higher precedence operator.

Answer (score -1):

If all you're after is the variables a to e on a single line, couldn't you just separate them with commas and call Print?

```
Print a,b,c,d,e
```

Comment: Otherwise you need to define k as a proper python type. For instance a tuple: `k=(a,b,c,d,e)`

Comment: I think the idea isn't to get them on a single line but to evaluate the expression, where `b` is expected to act as an operator.

Comment: Ah ok. I misunderstood, clearly

Answer (score -2):

`k = a b c d e` would give you error because this is not permitted. You could do it like:

```
if b == "+" and d == "+":
    k = a + c + e
elif b == "+" and d == "-":
    k = a + c - e
```

And etc.

Comment: That won't fix anything. Firstly, because Python doesn't do scopes inside if statement and for loops, and secondly because the problem is that `a b c d e` is invalid syntax, not a case of a name error.